# Duplicate GlobalKey detected in Widget Tree or Multiple Widgets used the same GlobalKey

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried to create form to input something from textfield to database using rest service, it worked just fine from the first try, but it got error the next time I tried, the error said there was something wrong with the GlobalkKey, so it's maybe around here.

```
class _DeliveryRecieverState extends State<DeliveryReciever> {
  List datas;
  File imagePath;
  bool validasi = false;
  String namaPenerima;
  final _keyFormReceiver = GlobalKey<FormState>();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    datas = this.datas;
    print(datas);

    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 1,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.local_shipping),
                  text: "Bukti Delivery",
                ),
              ],
            ),
            elevation: 0.1,
            // backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[800],
            flexibleSpace: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [Color(0xFF17ead9), Color(0xFF6078ea)]),
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(
              "Delivery",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "Popins-Bold",
                fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(46),
                letterSpacing: .6,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
            ],
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(470),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.black12,
                                  offset: Offset(0.0, 15.0),
                                  blurRadius: 15.0),
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.black12,
                                  offset: Offset(0.0, -10.0),
                                  blurRadius: 10.0)
                            ]),
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 16.0, right: 16.0, top: 16.0),
                            child: Form(
                              key: _keyFormReceiver,
                              autovalidate: validasi,
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    "Nama Penerima",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize:
                                            ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(30),
                                        fontFamily: "Poppins-Bold",
                                        letterSpacing: .6),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height:
                                        ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(30),
                                  ),                                  
                                  TextFormField(
                                    validator: validasiReceivername,
                                    onSaved: (String nama) {
                                      namaPenerima = nama;
                                    },
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintText: "Nama Penerima",
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            fontSize: 12.0)),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height:
                                        ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(50),
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                        child: RaisedButton(
                                          elevation: 7.0,
                                          color: Colors.green,
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                          child: Text("LANJUT"),
                                          textColor: Colors.white,
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(10)),

                                          onPressed: () {
                                            parseData();
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            height: 55.0,
            child: BottomAppBar(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [Color(0xFF17ead9), Color(0xFF6078ea)]),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => halamanUtama()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.nature_people, color: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => UpcomingDelivery()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.local_shipping, color: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ListDelivery()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  String validasiReceivername(String value) {
    if (value.length == 0) {
      //Toast.show("Password more than 4 ", context,duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.CENTER);
      return "Nama penerima tidak boleh kosong.";
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  void parseData() async {
    if (_keyFormReceiver.currentState.validate()) {
      _keyFormReceiver.currentState.save();
      _keyFormReceiver.currentState.reset();

      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => CustomerSignatureProof(
                  created_name: widget.created_name,
                  wmsorders_id: widget.wmsorders_id,
                  imagePath: widget.imagePath,
                  imageName: widget.imageName,
                  receiverName: namaPenerima,
                  upcoming_id: widget.upcoming_id,
                  upcoming_sku: widget.upcoming_sku,
                  upcoming_sak: widget.upcoming_sak,
                  upcoming_qty: widget.upcoming_qty,
                  upcoming_shipstatid: widget.upcoming_shipstatid,
                  upcoming_picname: widget.upcoming_picname,
                  upcoming_pictelp: widget.upcoming_pictelp,
                  upcoming_ordermultipleid: widget.upcoming_ordermultipleid,
                  upcoming_orderdetid: widget.upcoming_orderdetid,
                  upcoming_coordinatorid: widget.upcoming_coordinatorid,
                  upcoming_shipmentid: widget.upcoming_shipmentid)));
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the error in terminal,

[image]

Have anybody face the same probles as me, please give your guidance..

Comment: It seems that some other widget has also been assigned the same widget key. Check where you have manually assigned widget keys

Comment: can you post the whole State class code? It will help pinpointing the widget key issue and resolve it.

Comment: did you try by making global key static ?

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi I've post the whole state class now..

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya How to do it..?

Comment: Just write static keyword in front of declaring global key.

Comment: @edodije I can't find duplication in your global key in the given state class code. try looking for `key:` in your whole project, you may find duplicate key somewhere.

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi I only used key: in the login page and in the delivery receiver, because they both had form that need validation..

Comment: in the `key` parameter, do you pass the same global key?

Comment: Do you mean the login and the delivery receiver..? @HarshvardhanJoshi

Comment: @edodije yep. I just trying to confirm that both keys are different and is created in respective parent widget's state class

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi Nope, it's different I used _keyLogin and _keyReceiver..

Comment: oh, okay. If you don't mind can you post whole code somewhere so that I can get a look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204587/discussion-between-edodije-and-harshvardhan-joshi).